# MYSQL UPDATE WITH ONE SUBQUERY

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT account_no,
       dater
FROM   tbl_margin_all
WHERE  dater = '01/08/18'
GROUP  BY account_no,
          dater
```

This gives me a 149 rows result.
I would now like to copy these results to an empty table.

```
UPDATE tbl_margin_date t2,
       (SELECT account_no,
               dater
        FROM   tbl_margin_all
        WHERE  dater = '01/08/18'
        GROUP  BY account_no,
                  dater) t1
SET    t2.dater = t1.dater
```

The above does not work and i cannot see why. dater is just a string holding a date. Both tables for dater are varchar(8). Account_no is varchar(6) for both. I don't think i can do a join as tbl_margin_date is empty. I have tried a join but that didn't work.
It just returned zero rows affected. Same for the above query with subquery

```
UPDATE tbl_margin_date t2
       JOIN (SELECT account_no,
                    dater
             FROM   tbl_margin_all
             WHERE  dater = '01/08/18'
             GROUP  BY account_no,
                       dater) t1
         ON t2.dater = t1.dater
            AND t2.account_no = t1.account_no
SET    t2.dater = t1.dater
```

No idea why at least my update with a subquery won't work. thanks

ADDITION . PLEASE NOTE I THINK I NEED TO USE GROUP BECAUSE I WANT TO 
select other columns from tbl_margin_all e.g. Count(consignment_number) AS cons.
My apologies!

TURNS OUT MY PROBLEM WAS I WAS USING UPDATE INSTEAD OF INSERT!

```
INSERT INTO tbl_margin_date (dater, account_no, cons)
SELECT dater, account_no, COUNT(cons) FROM tbl_margin_all WHERE dater='2018-01-02'
GROUP BY account_no, dater
```

SO THIS ABOVE QUERY WORKED FOR ME

Comment: you've got to expect this from newbies i'm afraid. we don't realise what is necessarily important in a question, it's not done intentionally. i thought by omitting it would simplify things. again newby stuff. i've put in an addition. thanks again for your answer

Comment: Phrase your question by showing sample input, the expected output, plus the logic.  That alone is usually enough to get an answer.

Comment: like i said a newbie isn't necessarily going to do that but now that you have told me curtly i had better do it before the police come a knockin! geez

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A firts  suggestion don't use grup by if you have not aggregation function , in this case you could use a DISTINCT clause

```
UPDATE tbl_margin_date t2
JOIN (
  SELECT  distinct account_no,
          dater
  FROM   tbl_margin_all
  WHERE  dater = '01/08/18'
 ) t1  ON t2.dater = t1.dater
        AND t2.account_no = t1.account_no
SET    t2.dater = t1.dater
```

second your update code is fo update the column dater with the dater column result of the subquery but in the subquery you use a where with dater = '01/08/18' ...this is equal to set t2.dater =  '01/08/18'

could you inseatd of an update the column dater  want update others column then or you simply want insert the result of the subquery in the table tbl_margin_date

then you should use

```
insert into  tbl_margin_date  (accont_no, dater)
SELECT  distinct account_no,     dater
FROM   tbl_margin_all
WHERE  dater = '01/08/18'
```

Comment: this looks great. i better go away and look up what aggregation function is and i've not used distinct before. am new to all this. your first suggestion looks perfect for me. yes the WHERE part is just for testing purposes to keep the query quick and i would be updating more than one column so first is ideal. will go away and give it a go and report back .. thanks scaisEdge

Comment: it looks like i will be selecting aggregates. i better change my question. my apologies. at least i think i need to select aggregates e.g. in tbl_margin_all i would want SUM(consignments) AS consignments. newbies can't even ask questions right :)

Comment: hi .. turns out i should have been using Insert and not update. So i used your insert example with group by and all worked well .. will mark as answer once 24 hours has passed. thanks for your time!!

Comment: @Rich   . you are welcome  .. upvoted ...  i like when someone understand the meaning of an answer ...bravo..